# Is there a way to avoid code resetting after each state update?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: What is being rendered]I have this code which is a code that generates a 10x10 grid and after that, it creates 5 boxes of sizes 5,4,3,2 and 1. And after each click on one of the boxes, the innerHTML of that button gets added with an x. And after that x is added, we set the turn state to false.

The problem is that after each state update, the code runs another time so the 5 boxes which are placed randomly, gets placed another time randomly. But I want that the boxes stay in the same place. Is there a way to avoid this code from running each time the state is changed?

```
import React, {useEffect  ,useState} from 'react'
import Ship from '../components/ShipGenerate.js'
import '../style/style.css'



function Grid(props) {

    const [grid, setGrid] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {


    let randomNumberArray = [...Array(1)].map(()=>(Math.random() * 7 | 0) + 11 * (Math.random() * 10 | 0))
    let randomNumberArray2 = [...Array(1)].map(()=>(Math.random() * 7 | 0) + 11 * (Math.random() * 10 | 0))
    let randomNumberArray3 = [...Array(1)].map(()=>(Math.random() * 7 | 0) + 11 * (Math.random() * 10 | 0))
    let randomNumberArray4 = [...Array(1)].map(()=>(Math.random() * 7 | 0) + 11 * (Math.random() * 10 | 0))
    let randomNumberArray5 = [...Array(1)].map(()=>(Math.random() * 7 | 0) + 11 * (Math.random() * 10 | 0))


    for (i = 0; i < props.data[0].size; i++) {

      let result = randomNumberArray.map(function(val){return ++val;})
      let finalResult = randomNumberArray.push(result[i])
  }

  for (i = 0; i < props.data[1].size; i++) {

    let result2 = randomNumberArray2.map(function(val) {return ++val})
    let secondResult = randomNumberArray2.push(result2[i])
  }

  for (i = 0; i < props.data[2].size; i++) {

    let result = randomNumberArray3.map(function(val){return ++val;})
    let finalResult = randomNumberArray3.push(result[i])
  }

  for (i = 0; i < props.data[3].size; i++) {

  let result2 = randomNumberArray4.map(function(val) {return ++val})
  let secondResult = randomNumberArray4.push(result2[i])
  }

  for (i = 0; i < props.data[4].size; i++) {

  let result2 = randomNumberArray5.map(function(val) {return ++val})
  let secondResult = randomNumberArray5.push(result2[i])
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < 110; i++) {
     if (randomNumberArray.includes(i)) {    // ---> checking with this condition if the index in the random array to give it a different className
        setGrid([<button className="hello"></button>])
      }
        else if (randomNumberArray2.includes(i)) {
          setGrid([<button className="hello"></button>])
        }
        else if (randomNumberArray3.includes(i)) {
          setGrid([<button className="hello"></button>])
        }
        else if (randomNumberArray4.includes(i)) {
        setGrid([<button className="hello"></button>])
        }
        else if (randomNumberArray5.includes(i)) {
          setGrid([<button className="hello"></button>])
        }
         else {
        setGrid([<button className="boxGrid"></button>])
     }
  }
}, [])


const onClick = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  e.target.textContent = "x"
  props.setTurn(false)
}



    return (
        <div>
  <div onClick={onClick} className="box">
    {grid}
  </div>


        </div>
    )
}

export default Grid
```

Here is the app.js

```
import './App.css';
import React, {useEffect  ,useState} from 'react'
import Ship from './components/ShipGenerate.js'
import Grid from './components/Grid.js'
import Enemy from './components/enemyGrid.js'

function App() {
  const data = [{name:"ship1", size: 4, hit: false},
{name:"ship2", size: 3, hit: false},
{name:"ship3", size: 2, hit: false},
{name:"ship4", size: 1, hit: false},
{name:"ship5", size: 0, hit: false},
  ]
  const [turn, setTurn] = useState(true)


  return (
    <div className="App">

      <Grid data={data} turn={turn} setTurn={setTurn}/>
      <Enemy data={data} style={{ marginTop: "20px" }} turn={turn} setTurn={setTurn}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you just want to run the grid generation code once when the component first renders?

You can use the [useEffect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) for this.

```
useEffect(() => {
    gridGeneration();
}, []);
```

The empty dependency array means that it will only run once. If you would like it to re-run when some state changes you can place state variables into that array.

Comment: when i try to put the function there it stops rendering the grid... or it jumps an error ```Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:```

Comment: Could you update your post with this code? I'm not sure where you are going wrong. Make sure the useEffect hook is on the outer body of the function.

Comment: already updated with useEffect like this it says that it can't be put in the upper part

Comment: You need to put useEffect in the Grid function. And you do not call Grid(). In useEffect you put all of the code responsible for generating the grid. So those for loops. Basically you put all the code that you want to only execute once

Comment: Already made the changes to the code, but in this way, the code loses all its styling and it just shows a blank page...

Comment: Right so you also need to save the grid data in a state (you can use the useState hook) rather than a prop. Props are not saved between re-renders. So save it as a state and use the state data in your app

Comment: Okay, I've made plenty of modifications but now the full grid is not rendering... Just one box... I've edited the post with an image of what is being rendered

Comment: You are setting the entire grid to a single array element so after that call there is only one element in your array. You should use console.logs to find these errors in the future. Just add console.log(grid) and see where it goes wrong